# Rotten Tomatoes API with Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json, movie, rotten-tomatoes

I'm new to Ruby & trying out this API. I want to build a simple game which asks an user for two movies names to guess / compare which one received a better audience rating or any other comparative parameter. The API is working and I tried substituting the code with the user input but that's where it breaks down. (I have also mentioned the class I am calling)

```
require_relative 'workspace/lib/select'
require_relative 'workspace/lib/brand'
require 'json'
require 'rest-client'



# puts "hello world"

def create_reviewer
    puts "What is your name?"
    name = gets.strip

    puts "So, #{name} what genre are you interested in?"
  genre = gets.strip


  Select.new(name, genre)

end

def create_brand
  puts "Enter the first brand"
  brand_a = gets.strip

  puts "Enter the second brand"
  brand_b = gets.strip

  Brand.new(brand_a, brand_b)
end

review = create_reviewer
brands = create_brand




def get_rotten_tomatoes

  response = JSON.load(RestClient.get('http://api.rottentomatoes.com/api/public/v1.0/movies.json?apikey=SECRET&q=#{brand_a}&page_limit=30'))
  response["movies"].map do |entry|
    brand_a = entry["ratings"]["audience_score"]
    brand_b = entry["ratings"]["critics_score"]
    final_score = {brand_a: audience_score, brand_b: critics_score}

    final_score
end


goodies = get_rotten_tomatoes
puts goodies

----
class Brand
  attr_accessor :brand_a, :brand_b

  def initialize(name, genre)
    @brand_a = brand_a
    @brand_b = brand_b
  end

  # def to_s
  #   "Tenant: #{@name} \n Credit Score: #{@credit_score}."
  # end
end
```